# While unstacking, getting error 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe on which I need to apply condition based on same values of rows in few columns and update other columns.

Input Dataframe initialization:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'exp':['1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y',],
    'mat':['1y','1y','1y','2y','2y','2y','1y','1y','1y',],
    'reg':['in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in','in','in','in'],
    'con':['5w','5s','5c','5w','5s','5c','10w','10s','10c'],
    'pcon':['w','s','c','w','s','c','w','s','c'],
    'val':[2.5,0,-2.5,2.5,0,-2.5,5,0,-5],
    'rs':[6, 10, 4, 12, 30, 6,30,25,10]
})
df
```

Input DataFrame:

```
    exp mat reg con pcon    val   rs
0   1y  1y  in  5w  w       2.5    6
1   1y  1y  in  5s  s       0.0   10
2   1y  1y  in  5c  c      -2.5    4
3   1y  2y  in  5w  w       2.5   12
4   1y  2y  in  5s  s       0.0   30
5   1y  2y  in  5c  c      -2.5    6
6   1y  1y  in  10w w       5.0   30
7   1y  1y  in  10s s       0.0   25
8   1y  1y  in  10c c      -5.0   10
```

Expected Output DataFrame

```
    exp mat reg con pcon    val  rs
0   1y  1y  in  5w  w       2.5   5     # (6+4)/2 from input
1   1y  1y  in  5s  s       0.0  10     # Same as input
2   1y  1y  in  5c  c      -2.5   1     # (6-4)/2 from input
3   1y  2y  in  5w  w       2.5   9 
4   1y  2y  in  5s  s       0.0  30
5   1y  2y  in  5c  c      -2.5   3
6   1y  1y  in  10w w       5.0  20
7   1y  1y  in  10s s       0.0  25
8   1y  1y  in  10c c      -5.0  10
```

Multiple conditions are based on rows and columns:

1. For same values in rows of columns
   like for all 3 rows having exp=1y, mat=1y, reg=in.

   a. Update column 'rs' based on col 'con'.

   ```
     if 'con' == 5w, then rs = (current_rs + rs(con == 5c)) / 2  i.e (6+4)/2 
     if 'con' == 5s, then no changes
     if 'con' == 5c, then rs = (rs(con == 5w) - current_rs)) / 2 i.e (6-4)/2
     (Similarly for group of 10w, 10s, 10c in above example, in my dataset I have values till 100000w, 100000s, 100000c)
   ```
2. Apply same conditions from group of 3 rows, where exp=1y, mat=2y, reg=in

My dataset is quite large and there any many other regions and many more combinations of 'exp', 'mat' and 'reg' columns.

When I'm trying below code,
If I unstack the data so that 'pcon' becomes the column, I'm getting below error

```
"ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" error
```

Code:

```
tmp = df.set_index(['exp','mat','reg', 'pcon']).unstack() ## Failing here
tmp[('rs','w')],tmp[('rs','c')] = ((tmp[('rs','w')] + tmp[('rs','c')])/2,
                                  (tmp[('rs','w')] - tmp[('rs','c')])/2)
tmp = tmp.stack().reset_index()
```

If I unstack the data so that 'con' becomes the column, I'm getting below error

```
KeyError: ('rs', 'w')
```

Code

```
tmp = df.set_index(['exp','mat','reg', 'con']).unstack() ## Failing here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we want to unstack a dataframe it should have unique index otherwise it will be ambiguous for interpreter to unstack the dataframe because of duplicate index.
In above case, the error 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' was thrown because during set_index() the index was duplicated.

```
df.set_index(['exp','mat','reg', 'pcon'])
```

In order to keep the index unique, we can create a new column which would keep the index unique.

```
df['tem'] = df['con'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Then there won't be duplicate index and unstack can be applied on dataframe and calculations can be performed on 'rs' column.

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'exp':['1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y','1y',],
    'mat':['1y','1y','1y','2y','2y','2y','1y','1y','1y',],
    'reg':['in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'in','in','in','in'],
    'con':['5w','5s','5c','5w','5s','5c','10w','10s','10c'],
    'pcon':['w','s','c','w','s','c','w','s','c'],
    'val':[2.5,0,-2.5,2.5,0,-2.5,5,0,-5],
    'rs':[6, 10, 4, 12, 30, 6,30,25,10]
})
df['tem'] = df['con'].str.extract('(\d+)')
tmp = df.set_index(['exp','mat','reg', 'tem', 'pcon']).unstack()
tmp[('rs','w')],tmp[('rs','c')] = ((tmp[('rs','w')] + tmp[('rs','c')])/2,
                                  (tmp[('rs','w')] - tmp[('rs','c')])/2)
tmp = tmp.stack().reset_index()
tmp
```

Output DataFrame:

```
    exp mat reg tem pcon    con   val   rs
0   1y  1y  in  10  c       10c   -5.0  10.0
1   1y  1y  in  10  s       10s    0.0  25.0
2   1y  1y  in  10  w       10w    5.0  20.0
3   1y  1y  in  5   c        5c   -2.5  1.0
4   1y  1y  in  5   s        5s   0.0   10.0
5   1y  1y  in  5   w        5w   2.5   5.0
6   1y  2y  in  5   c        5c  -2.5   3.0
7   1y  2y  in  5   s        5s  0.0    30.0
8   1y  2y  in  5   w        5w  2.5    9.0
```

(tem column can be dropped as per requirement)